# Replace job in Kubernetes via Python

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have the following code:

```
 kubectl get job <JOB-NAME> -o json | jq 'del(.spec.selector)' | jq 'del(.spec.template.metadata.labels)' | kubectl replace --force -f -
```

That replaces an existing Kubernetes job with itself. Is it possible to do this with the Python Kubernetes API?

Here's what I am trying to do now:

```
import kubernetes as kubernetes
from kubernetes import client, config

# Configs can be set in Configuration class directly or using helper utility
config.load_kube_config()

configuration = kubernetes.client.Configuration()
name = "job-1"
namespace = "default"

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()

# Grab the exact name of the pod based on the job
metabase_create_readonly_user_name = ''
pods = v1.list_namespaced_pod(namespace, label_selector='job-name={}'.format(name), watch=False)
for pod in pods.items:
    job_name = pod.metadata.name


# THIS DOES NOT WORK!
v1.replace_namespaced_pod(job_name, namespace)
```

However, `replace_namespaced_pod` needs a `body` passed in as a parameter, so I'm not sure what to give it there. Is there a way to grab the exact body of the existing job and pass it in here?

Comment: In your command line you're operating on a Job resource, but in your Python code you're operating on a Pod. These are not at all the same thing. To get something equivalent to your command line you will need to update your Python code to fetch the named Job resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kubectl replace command has a **--force** option which actually does not use the replace, i.e., PUT, API endpoint. It **forcibly deletes** (DELETE) and then **recreates**, (POST) the resource using the provided spec.

According to the [kubernetes python client docs](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/tree/master/kubernetes):

Under the class `BatchV1Api`([Api](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/BatchV1Api.md)), there are 3 methods:

`read_namespaced_job`, `delete_namespaced_job` and `create_namespaced_job`.

So the following code snippet will suffice:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config()

batch_v1 = client.BatchV1Api()
...
v1_job = batch_v1.read_namespaced_job(name, namespace)
# some processing to v1_job
v1_job.metadata.resource_version = None
v1_job.metadata.uid = None
# as in your example
v1_job.spec.selector = None
v1_job.spec.template.metadata.labels = None
...
# forcibly deletes
batch_v1.delete_namespaced_job(name, namespace)
# recreates
batch_v1.create_namespaced_job(namespace, v1_job)
```

Comment: This looks good, but can you comment what the processing to `v1_job` should be? I am having trouble getting it to run

Comment: I am getting this error: `field is immutable","field":"spec.template"}]},"code":422}` Are you sure we can pass `v1_job_dict` into the `body`?

Comment: @jipot Sorry I missed the --force option you specified. See the updated answer.

Comment: not sure if you would know, but when I re-create the job, it pulls in an old AWS secret. Is there a field I can set to `None` to get it to wipe out the previous secret and pull in the new one?

Comment: @jipot Not knowing what an AWS secret is, is it a `Secret` resource in Kubernetes, a image pull secret, or a service account secret?

Comment: it is a `Secret` resource in Kubernetes

Comment: What is the secret used for, pulling container images? @jipot